# Azure Bot Channels Registration with Channel section blank

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a problem with "Bot Channels Registration" service on Azure portal. After the service creation, the "Channels" section not load, only stay blank.

Screenshot:
[image: Pb]

Any help?

Comment: welcome to SO!  might get better help on an azure support site.  not really a programming question.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Andre, can you please open a new issue on our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new)

Comment: Got the same problem, did you start an issue in GitHub or perhaps worked out what was happening?

Comment: There are some known issues with the localization strings preventing non-English language users from loading the channel config page view.

Answer (score 1):

After several tests, I solved the problem by changing the language and region of the Azure portal to English (US).