# Azure Bot Service - Channel configuration page displays no content

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

When I configure the Azure Bot Service Channel, nothing happens. The screen turns white like the image below.

[image]

Comment: What OS/browser are you using (if applicable)? What is the expected outcome? Why do you expect it?  What have you tried? What configuration settings are you using?

Comment: Hi @Jose can you try opening the page in a new browser window? Does it change anything? How about when you log-out of Azure and log-back in? Let me know if that works.

Comment: Cody, thanks for the reply.
I was adjusting the configurations of the bot service on Azure, using the default configuration pattterns in documentation. The channel is the final configuration step for connecting the bot to the output device, be it Skype, Facebook Messenger, webchat, etc. I tried three different browsers and they all had the same issue: MS Edge (which is on the image), Chrome and Firefox. I expected to have access to the channels, which did not happen. Without the screen I cannot configure the bot, so I haven't tried anything else yet.

Comment: nilsw, thank you for the reply. I did try several pages and browsers. I also logged out and back in, erased and recreated the bot, and the issue is still the same.

Comment: The solution to the problem was found by André Secco (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009020/azure-bot-channels-registration-with-channel-section-blank). Just switch the language from Azure to English. In my case, the language was in Brazilian Portuguese and I made the change that worked..

Comment: Use the English language setting in the Azure portal. There are some known issues with localization strings that are preventing this view from loading.