# Blank channel tab in Azure for Bot Channels Registration

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, channel

Similar issue : [Azure Bot Channels Registration with Channel section blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009020/azure-bot-channels-registration-with-channel-section-blank)

But I will provide more information (and the Azure team on twitter asked me to open this)

So, when channel tab is clicked for my bot (type Bot Channels Registration), I have the following behavior :

- Firefox and chrome : nothing is displayed, in the console log there is a 401 error

[image: blank tab]

[image: Error log]

- Internet explorer : there is an error displayed by Azure

[image: An error occured when refreshing your login informations. Refresh and retry]

Note that I'm owner of my resource group.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a known issue & we're working to roll out a fix this week.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! I'm glad to hear that :) !

Comment: Note that this seems to occurs only with the french display. Switching to English fix the issue.